# Is it legal to use corporate public information in an (mobile) app?

Tags: copyright, software

I don't know how to ask my question correctly so I'll try to give you an example of what situation I'm unsure about.

An Organizer is holding an event (e.g. a conference) and distributes tickets (maybe for free) but available to the public.  He also publishes a timetable for the event on his website so everybody could check what is going on at the event.

- Am I allowed to use this information in my application along with the
  name of the event *(just the information not the given representation)* or do I have to ask the organizer if I can show my users this information?
- What if I sell the access to view this information in my
  application?

By "information" I mean dates/calendar entries (e.g. Event "A" is happening on dd/mm/yyyy at hh:mm:ss in "City"), not editorial content.

I'm located in Germany but the app would be accessible "worldwide".

Comment: How are you accessing the information? By a public RSS feed? Or a private method you developed for the App? And does this concern one corporation? Or many? And if one corporation: does their TOS use of the information?

Comment: I access them by visiting websites and writing them off. It will concern many corporations/organisations.

Comment: OK, visiting each site yourself and copying the information could be seen as a copyright violation. But, in your comment below, you mention a blog? Are you manually writing about these conference dates/times on a blog?  Or developing an App that automatically collects and distributes information? Blogging about Apple's Dev Conference is very different than building and distributing an App that automatically takes Apple's information and distributes it. You need to be very clear on what you are doing.

Comment: no, I'm developing an application which is displaying events (sort of a calender), and as I'm not organizing these events I need to get these Informations ( when, how long and where an event will occure) from the organizers of these events. And the way i access the informations is the same way anyone would get the information if they wannt to visit an event. By website, picture, facebook page, twitter or any other way companys are promoting their event so people will participate. sorry for my poor english!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where you are, and where the company is.  [In the US, facts are not copyrightable](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/499/340/), but I don't know about Germany, or anywhere outside the US for that matter.  So, it depends on the jurisdiction that you would, hypothetically, be sued in.

Answer (score 0):

The information is publicly available. Everybody can read it. Assuming that the information was made publicly available by the copyright holder, everybody has the right to read it.

Nobody except the copyright holder has the right to copy the information without permission of the copyright holder. Giving you permission to read the information doesn't give you permission to copy it.

Comment: ok, so i wont be allowed to share these informations in any way? ... 'say if Apple announces their developer conference will take place on the 2nd Juli 2016 at 16:00 , I'm not allowed to write about this in my blog because I'm copying informations from apple?

Comment: @phisto05 you are allowed to write about that. You are allowed to restate facts. Read *[Feist](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/499/340/)*. Copyright doesn't protect information, only the specific way it is expressed.